# How change updated_at from timestamp type to datetime?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Now field `updated_at` is as `datetime(3)`, so it invokes an error:

```
errors: "Trailing data"
```

Because Laravel expects timestamp type instead datetime. How to say Laravel that it is datetime field?

Log file is:

```
[2019-06-02 14:41:07] local.ERROR: Trailing data {"userId":8,"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Trailing data atCarbon\\Traits\\Creator.php:537)
[stacktrace]
esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Traits\\Creator.php(559): Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-06-07 00:0...', NULL)
```

I tried this:

```
const UPDATED_AT = "AT_lastupdateuser";

protected $casts = [
    'AT_lastupdateuser' => 'datetime',
];
```

Comment: Why not change the timestamp to daytime in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast an attribute to your model by adding a specific key/value to the `$cast` array of your model. See here for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

In your case you should add the following array to your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'updated_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Comment: Please see my question again